# User defined number ranges

Tags: php

I have a function where for a specific number range a percentage has to be applied:

- 0-100 EUR: 5%
- >100 EUR: 3%

This number ranges and percentages should be **user-defined**.

The implementation should be as simple as possible.

What would you suggest for specifying the ranges and calculating the result?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to some kind of database, I'd store the values there. You would need 3 tables at minimum:

*ranges*

- id_range
- from_number
- until_number
- percentage

*users*

- id_user

*user-ranges*

- id_range
- id_user

Make the from_number and until_number columns nullable, to represent anything up to X and anything after Y.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my short approach for calculating the result with defined rules in an array

```
$rules = array(
  5 => '0-100 EUR', // here the percentages and their corresponding values
  3 => '> 100 EUR'
);

$rand = mt_rand(0, 100); // calculate a random percent value
$lastPercentage = 0;

foreach($rules as $percentage => $val) {

  // create a range from 0-5 (in the first iteration)
  // every next iteration it is lastPercentage + 1 (5 + 1 in this case) to lastPercentage + current percentage
  $range = range($lastPercentage, $percentage + $lastPercentage);

  // yep, it is in the percentage range
  if (in_array($rand, $range)) {
    echo $lastPercentage,' < '.$rand.' > '.($percentage + $lastPercentage);
  }

  $lastPercentage = $percentage + 1; // +1 so that there are no overlapping ranges
}
```